# Why do large companies need public address ranges?

Tags: ip-address

For example google states they own the public address range "8.8.4.0/24". Why would they need a whole block when they could use NAT. What factors contribute to this decision? Is it that they would exhaust a single address with subnetting and need more?

Comment: NAT is a kludge that was created to try to conserve IPv4 addresses until IPv6 becomes ubiquitous. NAT breaks the IP promise of a unique IP address for every device, and end-to-end connectivity. If they use NAT, then only one server could have a port forwarded to it, but suppose they need several servers using the port.

Comment: [This answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53937/8499) has a section about NAT problems.