# How are we still able to use IPv4 address even with NAT?

Tags: ip, ipv4, nat

My question is why haven't we run out of IPv4 public IP as well because now almost all home has a router which is assigned a public IP. Is it possible to have multiple layers of NAT on the router-ISP side as well?

How is it working exactly?

Comment: See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53937/8499) that goes into detail.

Comment: I did not exactly understand the part "if every home router is provided a Public IP by ISPs how are the IPv4 address still not over/depleted"

Comment: Because not every home router is provided a public IPv4 address. You should read the answer more carefully. There is a section that includes: "_To do that, **the ISPs are now starting to assign Private or Shared addresses to their home/residential customers**, and the ISPs use NAPT on their own routers to facilitate the use of multiple Private or Shared addresses on a single public address._"